# Do we havecustom console object in salesforce and if so how to create a console object in a developer org

Tags: salesforce

I am concerned that do we have custom console object in salesforce and if so then how do we create it in the developer object

Comment: Can you add more details to question? What does that means - "console object"? You can create any custom objects with any sets of fields, what's the problem?

Comment: I am suppose to prepare a document as how to create an article in Knowledge,there is a sample console in my developer org which can be enabled with specific profile,I did it for system admin.Now in case pagelaout ,I clicked on layout properties and knowledge sidebar is checked.Now if you click on the sample app on the top right corner of the box,you click on the on the case on the new UI,you get Knowledge article on the corner.But now I have been asked to create a custom console object to do whole work.My question is do we have custom console object.